# Differentiability implies continuity with alternate form

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand graphically how a differentiability implies continuity. However how can I prove it using this form of the derivative definition:

$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}
$$

Comment: The definition assume that $f(a+h)\to f(a)$. If is not the case then the limit of the derivative in $a$ doesnt exist.

Comment: $f(a+h)-f(a)=h\cdot\left(\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right)$. As $h\to0$, this expression tends to 0, so $f(a+h)$ tends to $f(a)$, which means $f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

Answer (score 0):

If that ratio tends to a finite limit when the denominator tends to zero, that means that also the numerator tends to zero. And that means continuity.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$$
Then
$$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}=f'(x)+\alpha (x),$$
where if $x \rightarrow a$ then $\alpha (x) \rightarrow0$.

Then $$f(x) - f(a)=\left( f'(x)+\alpha (x)\right)(x-a)$$

Consequently $f(x) \rightarrow f(a)$ at $x \rightarrow a$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that the derivative exists implies that the function $f$ is defined at $x=a$, and furthermore on some little interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon>0$.  Now

$$f'(a):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

by definition.  In particular for all $h$ with $0<|h|<\epsilon$ we have the following by basic algebra:

$$f(a+h)-f(a)=h\cdot\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

This noting that the limits both exist we have the following by basic limit properties:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}(f(a+h)-f(a))
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(h\cdot\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right) \\
&=\left(\lim_{h\to0}h\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right) \\
&=0\cdot f'(a)=0
\end{align*}

Now I'll leave it to you to show the following straightforward result (if you haven't already):

**Lemma:** For a real function $f$ defined at $a$ the following are equivalent:

1) Function $f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

2) The limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

3) The limit $\lim_{h\to0}(f(a+h)-f(a))=0$.

Using this Lemma we have right away that $f$ is continuous (as desired).